# Navigation Components: Bottom navigation setup with navcontroller and custom action

Tags: android, navigation

I am trying to add custom action to bottomnavigation item click (before it actually gets clicked) but I've set BottomNavigation with Navcontroller like this so that it

```
 NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(composeBottomNavView, navController);
```

I'd like to show an ad inbetween bottomnavigation item click before navigating automatically.

Answer (score 1):

add a listener for navController when destination is changed , this way you can do whatever you want when some fragment is about to get displayed , like this :

navController.setOnDestinationChangedListener(this);

and then override the method :

```
@override
public void onDestinationChanged(NavController controller, NavDestination destination, Bundle arguments){
//here you can do what you want , like checking destinationId or show a dialog or an ad on the screen , then call this :
navController.navigate(destination.getId);
}
```